# How to get start value with Year in Unix/Linux command or any other way python also fine?

Tags: linux, unix, unix-timestamp

i need output with Year in start field, below command i am using in Linux to get the License details but i am getting date like(start Tue 1/7 9:54) , so want to know the year for this:

```
lmutil lmstat -a -c user@server_name -f abcd -t
```

Output : start Tue 1/7 9:54
Looking for start Tue 1/7(with year) 9:54

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I solve the issue by using the different way.

Comment: There is bug with this existing command and redhat should fix this as by default it's picking date without Year.